# How to pass unique_ptr to mock object as a function parameter

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to add some tests to my project, using **gtest**/**gmock**. I have a problem with testing a function that takes `const unique_ptr` to an object of another class.

Class `View` has some functions, including `get_description_from_user()` and `get_category_from_user()`. These functions get data entered by user in the terminal window. 
In class `PlanService` there is a function `create_plan()` that calls above functions from the class `View`. I have created a `MockView` class but I have no idea how to pass a pointer to object of this class as a parameter of `create_plan()` function.

Here is my code:

```
class MockView :
        public View {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(string, get_description_from_user, ( ));
    MOCK_METHOD(string, get_category_from_user, ( ));
};

TEST(create_plan, set_category_and_description)
{
    const unique_ptr<MockView> view(new MockView());
    EXPECT_CALL(*view, get_description_from_user()).WillOnce(Return("desc"));
    EXPECT_CALL(*view, get_category_from_user()).WillOnce(Return("cat"));

    PlanService plan_service;
    plan_service.create_plan(move(view)); //The problem is here.
    EXPECT_EQ(plan_service.get_category(), "cat");
    EXPECT_EQ(plan_service.get_description(), "desc");
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
no matching function for call to  ‘PlanService::create_plan(std::remove_reference<const  std::unique_ptr<MockView>&>::type)’ plan_service.create_plan(move(view));
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
Class `PlanService`

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Plan;
class View;

class PlanService {

public:
    PlanService() = default;
    virtual ~PlanService() = default;
    virtual void create_plan(const std::unique_ptr<View>& view);
    //... some more functions
    const std::string& get_description() const;
    const std::string& get_category() const;
private:
    std::string description;
    std::string category;
};
```

Definition of the `create_plan()` function:

```
void PlanService::create_plan(const unique_ptr<View>& view)
{
    description = view->get_description_from_user();
    category = view->get_category_from_user();
}
```

Class `View` is much more complicated because it uses ncurses library, so I don't add the implementation of this class.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, since I'm not sure what PlanService is and the signatures of create_plan.  Not sure why you made the view's unique pointer `const`, that seems odd.

Comment: @Eljay , I added a part of PlanService class declaration and the create_plan() function.

Comment: As a matter of style, create_plan should have this signature: `void PlanService::create_plan(View const& view)`.  Because it is not *taking ownership* of the object contained in the smart pointer, and by const-reference because the View passed in must *exist* (so doesn't need to be a `View const*` and allow-and-handle nullptr).  Only use a smart pointer as a parameter or a return when transferring ownership.  Otherwise assume any pointer parameter is merely "borrowed" only for the call (and may be null), or should be a reference (caller responsible for validity).

Comment: You have a mistake with the `const unique_ptr<MockView> view(new MockView());` line, it should be `const unique_ptr<View> view(new MockView());` and I expect that will fix your immediate problem.